# What should be the regular expression to accept time input for textfield in hh:mm format

Tags: ios, time, nsregularexpression

i want to validate the input to text field for time that can be in following formats:

1. 02:30
2. 2:30
3. 0230
4. 14:30

Currently i am using the regular expression :

```
^([0-9]{1,4})?(\\:([0-9]{1,2})?)?$
```

but this is not as desired.
Please help me out.

Comment: All listed inputs are valid?

Comment: it will also accept 12:80 which is the problem.

Comment: http://code4app.net/ios/RegEx-TextField/51d42b2b6803fa653d000002

Comment: It's probably easier to do it with `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):?([0-5][0-9])$
```

accept:

- 02:30
- 2:30
- 0230
- 14:30
- 230

not accept:

- 23
- 2:3
- 24:30
- 12:80